FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(authHeader.blob) is not verifying TokenID from Firebase
Context
I'm currently learning Ktor and have created a simple backend to authenticate users. To achieve this, I set up a Firebase account and integrated the Firebase Admin SDK into my Ktor project using a private key from Firebase.
What I Did
Creating a Mock User and Getting a Token ID:
I created a mock user in Firebase.
I used Postman to log in this mock user using the following URL:
bash
Code
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key={YOUR_FIREBASE_API_KEY}
The response from this request provided me with an ID token.
Sending the Token to My Ktor Server:
I took the ID token from the previous step and sent it to my Ktor server.
I included the token in the Authorization header of my request, using the "Bearer" scheme.
The Problem
I implemented a function in Ktor to verify the Firebase ID token using FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(authHeader.blob). Here’s the code:
suspend fun verifyFirebaseIdToken(
    call: ApplicationCall, 
    authHeader: HttpAuthHeader, 
    tokenData: suspend ApplicationCall.(FirebaseToken) -> Principal?
): Principal? {

    val token: FirebaseToken = try {
        if (authHeader.authScheme == BEARER_HEADER && authHeader is HttpAuthHeader.Single) {
            logger.info("MORGAN DEBUG - VerifyIdToken - Token: ${authHeader.blob}")
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(authHeader.blob)
            }
        } else {
            null
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        call.respondRedirect(Endpoints.Unauthorized.path)
        return null
    } ?: return null

    return tokenData(call, token)
}

The Issue
When the code reaches FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(authHeader.blob), it's supposed to verify the token by communicating with Firebase. However, it isn't returning a response or verified token as expected. Instead, I see a log message indicating an issue with token verification:

token_verification with provider example.com.firebase.FirebaseAuthProvider@536cc804.

What I'm Trying to Understand
I'm trying to figure out why the token verification isn't working as expected and why FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken() isn't returning the expected response from Firebase.
see previous description.
